# VLCj transcoding and file saving

Tags: java, vlc, libvlc, vlcj

I want to develop a webcam recording java application shall shall work seamlessly on Windows, Linux and Mac. I am using the VLCj CaptureTest.java class provided by caprica software. I have a few queries and problems:

1. Capture device MRL are give for Windows (dshow://) and Linux (v4l2:///dev/video0) but none for Mac.
2. Only audio media option is given for Linux i.e. :input-slave=alsa://hw:0,0
   What about Windows and Mac ?

I also have problems in transcoding that are very tricky. No video is shown when I run the class, a black window is shown and only an audio file is created for the following sout :

```
String[] options = {              ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:file{dst=" + fileName + "},dst=display}",
              ":input-slave=alsa://hw:0,0"
    };
```

Video and audio are shown and heard but no file is created for the following sout:

```
String[] options = {
              ":sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128,deinterlace}:duplicate{dst=display,dst=file{dst=" + fileName + "}'",
              ":input-slave=alsa://hw:0,0"
  };
```

and

```
String[] options = {
              ":sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128,deinterlace}:standard{access=file,mux=ts,dst=" + fileName + "}'",
":input-slave=alsa://hw:0,0"
            };
```

I had been searching Google and Stackoverflow but I didnt get what I need. Apologies for my lack of knowledge in VLCj

Comment: This is not specifically `VLCJ` issue; it is how you use `libVLC` engine and `sout` VLC command. Test the `sout` command using `VLC` media player first before putting it as the option string in `VLCJ`. Of course, there are a few problems here and there, but you will figure it out.

Comment: now the problem has solved. vcodec=mp4v was the main problem, i changed vcodec=mp2v and all started working. The working sout chain is :  ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,vb=4096,scale=1,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=file{dst=" + fileName + "},dst=display,select=noaudio}" ............... fileName has to have .mpg extension.

Answer (score 0):

the main reason is recording a video depends on the input video and we should choose the right codec (or transcode) for this type of video.
Probably, You can try at first record the input video with VLC that produce the string option and then only choose the correct the option which make video visible!!!!!